# How can I view Ruby objects in some more readable format?

Tags: ruby

Is it some way to format console-printed Ruby object to be more readable? For JS we can use JSON formatters, but I can't find any equivalent for this specific Ruby format.

Comment: Perhaps the [`awesome_print`](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print) gem is what you are looking for?

Comment: What kind of object, and what format do you want? Kernel#pp is built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Sergio Tulentsev I have the simplest way of doing this:

```
JSON.pretty_generate(my_object.as_json)
```

Although we should remember that the JSON object is available by default only with Rails.

Comment: If you copy it from console to paste into an external formatter, you don't need to do that. Try `puts JSON.pretty_generate(my_object)` instead.

Comment: Hm, I don't understand your point. Using `pretty_generate` results in the error for me: `JSON::GeneratorError (only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed)`, while `to_json` works fine. Generally I use it for ActiveRecords in Rails.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thought you're using it on hashes. In this case, you could do `JSON.pretty_generate(my_object.as_json)`

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it works without the need of copying and pasting :)